# Script fails when running normally but in debug its fine

Tags: google-sheets

I'm developing a google spreadsheet that is automatically requesting information from a site, below is the code. The variable 'tokens' is an array consisting of about 60 different 3 letter unique identifiers. The problem that i have been getting is that the code keeps failing to request all information on the site. Instead it falls back (at random) on the validation part, and fills the array up with "Error!" strings. Sometimes its row 5, then 10-12, then 3, then multiple rows, etc. When i run it in debug mode everythings fine, can't seem to be able to reproduce the problem.

Already tried to place a sleep (100ms) but that fixed nothing. Also looked at the amount of traffic the API accepts (10 requests per second, 1.200 per minute, 100.000 per day) , it shouldn't be a problem.

Runtime is limited so i need it to be as efficient as possible. I'm thinking it is an issue of computational power after i pushed all values in the json request into the 'tokens' array. Is there a way to let the script wait as long as necessary for the changes to be committed?

```html
function newGetOrders() {
  var starttime = new Date().getTime().toString();
  var refreshTime = new Date();
  var tokens = retrieveTopBin();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('aaafFzbXXRzSi-eXBu9Xh81Ne2r09vM8rLFkA4fY').getSheetByName("Sheet37");
  sheet.getRange('A2:OL101').clear();
  for (var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
    var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=" + tokens[i][0] + "BTC", {muteHttpExceptions:true});
    var json = JSON.parse(request.getContentText());
    tokens[i].push(refreshTime);
    Utilities.sleep(100);
    for (var k in json.bids) {
      tokens[i].push(json.bids[k][0]);
      tokens[i].push(json.bids[k][1]);
    }
    for (var k in json.asks) {
      tokens[i].push(json.asks[k][0]);
      tokens[i].push(json.asks[k][1]);
    }
    if (tokens[i].length < 402) {
      for (var x=tokens[i].length; x<402; x++) {
      tokens[i].push("ERROR!");
      }
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, tokens.length, 402).setValues(tokens);
}
```

Comment: Some more information on the issue: if i remove the validation check if the array has a sufficient length for setValues i get the error that the length was unexpected, the length is 2 instead of 402 meaning the data is not pushed into the 'tokens' variable. For whatever reason, because i checked and the request should come through (i verified with my browser). I also tried to use another variable in case the 'tokens' variable was locked up but it didn't solve the issue either.

Comment: I have created a work around, a while loop that checks for json to have any error code returned and while it does, keep retrying. It will do this for its maximum runtime (which is 5 min). It's not elegant but functional. Still hoping somebody can explain the reason behind this issue as well as how to solve it.

Comment: If your latest script is different from that of your question, can you show us your latest script? If you can do, update your question.

Comment: If you have answer please post as one instead of editing out the question